# Xamarin Forms save the state of a switch on a prebuilt sqlite database

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

Ok so my app has a mini problem that I don't know how to save the state of a switch with my prebuilt database (the point is to have a lost of objects and the user can click the switch to mark that they have it, and to allow the data to persist even when app is closed(my main problem))

**Item.cs** "were I have names of the table model"

```
public class Bag
{
    [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Object{ get; set; }
    public bool Check { get; set; }

}
```

**DatabaseData.cs** "this is in the services folder"

```
public class DatabaseData
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _database;

    public static string DbPath { get; } = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "data.sqlite");

    public DatabaseData()
    {
        _database = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath);
        _database.CreateTable<Bag>();
    }


    public List<Bulto> List()
    {
        return _database.Table<Bag>().ToList();
    }
}
```

**BagPage.xaml** "This is were the user sees the page (ignore ugly UI)"

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Bag}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label FontSize= "Medium" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Object}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Switch Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsToggled="{Binding Check}" OnColor="{StaticResource Primary}" ThumbColor="LightGray"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

**BagPage.xaml.cs** "What I have atm in the code behind"

```
public partial class BagPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Bag> Bag { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Bag>();
    public BagPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App1.data.sqlite"))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                File.WriteAllBytes(DatabaseData.DbPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        DatabaseData repository = new DatabaseData();
        foreach (var Bag in repository.List())
        {
            Bag.Add(bag);
        }

        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: to start with, you should copy your db to a local folder in app startup, and only do it **once**.  Doing it in the page is not a great design.  Second, a switch is a boolean control, so you should probably model is with a `bool` property, not a string.  Third, why would you bind that property to both a Label and a Switch?  Finally, have you looked at the docs on how to insert or update a single row of the table?  You will need methods to do that in your db class.  Bonus - the PK of a db table is generally an auto-incrementing `int`, not a `string`

Comment: *"user can click the switch to mark that they have it, and to allow the data to persist"* - Usually the app dev (you) would program it so that this happens **automatically**. Is there any reason to require the user to click a switch? Every time the app starts, query your database on server (or cloud) for any updates, then add those to a local database file or folder [as Jason suggests]. I typically have the server include an `update timestamp` in the sent data, so that when app talks to server next time, it can provide that `update timestamp`. So the server only needs to send recent changes.

Comment: ok so i moved the db to  a subfolder, idk how to run it once, i do know that its not great to have it run every time, i did fix the bool(i forgot to do it), the reason i binded it to a label was to see that it worked correctly

Comment: like the reason why i want the user to click a switch is cuz the app has a prefilled list of items and the users simply "check off" if they have the item, like what i dont know is how to make it so the app retains the switch state

Answer (score 0):

As Jason suggested, the Primary Key should be a Integer, not a String.Also, the state of the switch should be defined as boolean in the table.You should define the Bag table like below:

```
   public class Bag
   {
      [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Object { get; set; }
      public bool Check { get; set; }
   }
```

Please refer to official docs for more details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: yea i simply forgot to change it since i used the default template (plus this is like the 3rd time i had to restart from zero)

Comment: That's OK.I also recommend you go through a online tutorial on the xamarin sqlite database.

Comment: ok so after a few weeks of learning i came to a mini problem, to safe the state my code needs to be async, but when i change everything to its async counterpart i get this error in the foreach "CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Task<List<Bulto>>' because 'Task<List<Bulto>>' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: and the foreach is what shows everything thats in the database.....